# Someone stole whole content of my site and is already outranking me in Google

Tags: wordpress, web, seo, google-search

I have a small problem. Few days (like week almost) my traffic to site http://kinotip.eu/ starts hitting zero number.

I found out, that when I google "*kinotip eu*", other site is in first results - http://mohachat.org/. They stole whole content of my web.

Is there any option how? Can you tell me how to stop this? And yes, system that my site using is WordPress.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. It might be on topic at [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to completely stop someone from stealing your content, but of course, you can make it hard and time-consuming for them to do that.
you can use WordPress plugins like: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protection/

Which will allows you to disabled actions like `copy/paste`, `drag drop`, `right click` on your website.

You can also Report this issue to google:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en&pli=1

this will block their website from google search forever.

Lastly, you can fill this DMCA form to remove the copyright content.
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1&